# How to get the first number after a decimal point of a Double?

Tags: swift, string, type-conversion, double, substring

I have a Double like this:

```
339.09965653839
```

How can I get the first number after the dot?

```
0 // desired result
```

I tried to look into similar questions but unfortunately I found only ways to separate a double in two parts also these two Double. I would like to have an Int and then be able to print it as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the digit as an `Int`, you can do a little math:

```
let someNum = 339.09965653839
let digit = Int((someNum - Double(Int(someNum))) * 10)
```

And of course it is trivial to display `digit` in/as a string as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Or, alternatively:

```
let number = 123.456

// 1234 % 123 = 4
let digit = Int(number * 10) % Int(number)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for some values of the denominator (always when he is below 10).

Answer (score 1):

Convert double to string and fetch the first character after dot.

```
let value = 339.09965653839
let valueInString = "\(value)".split(separator: ".")
print(valueInString[1].first ?? "")
```

Comment: This won't work for locale's which use decimal separators other than the `.` symbol and there's quite a few such locale's.

Answer (score 0):

`Double` extension made from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606165/611879):

```
extension Double {
    func firstDecimal() -> Int {
        Int((self - Double(Int(self))) * 10)
    }
}
```